# twitter continuous stream asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stream, twitter

This is my first post on stack overflow, but I have been using it for a long time. I would like to begin by saying thanks for the great community of developers who have helped me solve many problems as an undergrad student.

Now, I have been working on an asp.net project in which I want to get a twitter stream on a specific query (e.g. Star Trek), and always show a scrolling list of the last 10 or so tweets about it. I am also using a sentiment scorer and I want to show the scoring result for each tweet, probably next to the tweet itself.

So far, I have been able to create a simple console application in which I connect to the streaming api with the appropriate OAuth header and parse the json into a nice readable format. However, I now want to create an asp.net application like the one mentioned above. Many examples show how to do simple posts, or get the last 20 statuses from a user, and update  the page with those by returning a view, but none of these examples show how to deal with twitter's continuous/infinite stream.

My question is how do I relay the twitter stream in asp.net from a controller? Is it possible to return a view every time a new status comes into the stream? Or am I going in a completely wrong direction? I have also read about PushStreamContent - is it possible to relay the twitter stream using this method, and then possibly make an ajax call? I feel like that isn't the most simple solution. I also doubt I need to use threads.

I am very new to asp.net mvc, and perhaps mvc is not the best way of solving my problem. However, I would like to use it if I can. Any tips, methods, or help steering me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I hope this question is clear and specific enough.

Here is some example code of my TwitterStream class:

```
public void StartStream()
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = MakeRequest(); //makes oauth request
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        sReader = new StreamReader( resp.GetResponseStream() );
        while(true)
        {
            PopulateTweetJsonQueue(); //throw tweets into queue for processing
        }
    }
    catch(WebException e)
    {
        BackOffStrategy(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe? http://alchemywebsockets.net/

Comment: Possibly. I see that it is a persistent connection - Would this allow me to write the twitter feed through it, and I could just open a socket on the client side and keep it open as long as I want?

Comment: dmcnally1023, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

With this method,you can Post Tweets and also redirect

```
public ActionResult Tweet(string tweet)
        {
            var twitter = new WebConsumer(TwitterConsumer.ServiceDescription, this.TokenManager);
            // Process the response
            var accessTokenResponse = twitter.ProcessUserAuthorization();

            // Is Twitter calling back with authorization?
            if (Tweet_Token != null)
            {
                string accessToken = Tweet_Token;
                var tokenSecret = twitter.TokenManager.GetTokenSecret(accessToken);
                TwitterPush tw = new TwitterPush(twitter_app, twitter_secret, accessToken, tokenSecret);
                if (tweet != "")
                {
                    var response = tw.UpdateStatus(tweet);

                }
                return View();

            }  return View();
        }
```